# SQL Server HEAP Tables WITH Clustered Index , how is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

I have a database that shows a few tables as HEAP, even since I am sure all of them have Clustered indexes and some even have a few Non-Clustered indexes, since a long time ago.

my understanding for HEAP table is : "A heap is a table without a clustered index"

as seen in the image, this tables **have a clustered index**

[image: heap tables with clustered index]

Currently using SQL Server 2014 with Compatibility mode 120

then , **why are this tables being shown as heap** when they have a clustered index ?

Thanks!

Comment: Well....am I looking at your image wrong?, it says that the index are non-clustered....

Comment: PK != Clustered index, if that's the bad assumption behind this question...

Comment: screw me and my vision !    how could I miss that !

Comment: you guys are correct,   lamark and Damien_the_unbeliever, thanks for your attention, I am laughing at myself now  !